# onDestroy() - to set or not to set instance variables to null?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Is it a good idea to specifically set the instance variables to null in onDestroy() callback of the activity? Something like this:

```
    @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mClassVariable1 = null;
    mClassVariable2 = null;
    mClassVariable3 = null;
}
```

If I remember correctly from Java SE, any references that are isolated & not connected to a running program & can be garbage collected anyways. So does this make the above superfluous?

On the other hand, the lifecycle in mobile devices being different, would the above be a best-practice?

I know it *cannot hurt* to do it, but sometimes there are a number of class variable (references to indivudual UI elements etc), so I'd really like to know for my own understanding, what's really going on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Question: Although OnDestroy() is called when you either exit an activity or rotate your device, is the class still kept instantiated? If it is, wouldn't it be dangerous to nullify variables.

Comment: @Salsero69: A very good question. I'm not sure, hoping the answers here would answer it.

Comment: I also face same question, hope some one give more explanation. I also put instance variable null in on-destroy but not sure it work proper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had it right when you said that the garbage collector will pick up references that are isolated.  Specifically, any graph of references not connected to the execution thread will be collected.  Because of this, there is no good reason to set your variables to null that I can see.  Any advantages would be far outweighed by the code maintenance cost.

Comment: It can be neccessary to explicit null references in onDestroy. You are not guaranteed that your activity will kill right away and and therefore retain memory. Take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187004/large-memory-chunk-not-garbage-collected

Comment: Setting your instance variables to null in onDestroy is not the answer.  Look for leaks in which you retain a reference to the destroyed activity.  onDestroy means the system is done with the Activity.  Be sure your code is as well.